# How can I create RAR archives using Windows RT?

Tags: rar, windows-rt

How can I create RAR archives on a Microsoft Surface RT tablet that has Windows RT? I can only create ZIP archives currently.

Comment: @slm: Where are the downloads for ARM architecture (or CPU independent .NET)?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, for now. Since it's a proprietary closed format and nothing except RAR or WinRAR can *create* RAR archives, until an official Windows Store app is released this is not possible. (Well, it might be possible if someone reverse-engineered the format, but that would be illegal and I highly doubt such an app will ever be approved by Microsoft or survive a legal challenge.)

Since the [UnRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm) code is open source, programs like [8 Zip](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/8-zip/0ca9b05e-9acb-4b91-a3f2-8d2c7545b0fe) can extract RAR archives (using 7-Zip's DLL/code for archive support). An alternative to the common ZIP format though is 7-Zip's 7z, which is on par in terms of compression ratios with RAR, and being open source is supported completely (i.e. both creation and extraction) by 8 Zip.